# Is there a way to use PyCharm to code over MonkeyRunner

Tags: android, python, pycharm, monkeyrunner

I was wondering if anyone ever tried to use [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) to code scripts for [MonkeyRunner](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) for Android, and how to do it ?

Comment: I have used MonkeyRunner but moved to ADB since it is more flexible. I would recommend to write your tests in shell.

Comment: Use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) which works very well with pycharm and you get UI and automatic test generation for free.

Comment: I believe PyCharm uses the installed Python version on your system.  Mine is Python3.  As that, MonkeyRunner (and Jython) aren't really compatible with Python3.